# How to chaincall functions in useEffect more elegantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This code works but I'm still getting my head around react hooks and wonder if it could be written more elegantly/there's any logical flaws I should consider.

*What I'm trying to do:*

1. Get an *image source data* using `useContext`
2. Call a function - pass in the *image source data* as an argument, manipulate the format, then make an API call with it.
3. Once the API data returns, call a function to return an array of values
4. Set the values as a state which populates the DOM

*Here's my code:*

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'

import { ImageSrcContext } from '../../App'

const Boxes = () => {
  const { imageSrc } = useContext(ImageSrcContext)
  const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState([])

  const fetchApiData = useCallback(async (imgSrc) => {
    const ImageString = imgSrc.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '')

    let response = await fetch('/image', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        ImageString,
      }),
    })
    response = await response.json()
    return response
  }, [])

  const getBoxStyles = useCallback(
    async (data) => {
      const boxes = data.outputs.regions

      return boxes.map((box) => {
        const {
          top,
          right,
          bottom,
          left,
        } = box.bounding_box
        return {
          top: `${top * 100}%`,
          right: `${100 - right * 100}%`,
          bottom: `${100 - bottom * 100}%`,
          left: `${left * 100}%`,
        }
      })
    },
    []
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchApiData(imageSrc)
      .then((res) => {
        return getBoxStyles(res)
      })
      .then((res) => {
        return setBoxes(res)
      })
  }, [fetchApiData, imageSrc, getBoxStyles])

  return (
    <>
      {Boxes.map((box, i) => {
        const { top, right, bottom, left } = box

        return (
          <div
            key={i}
            className='image__Box'
            style={{
              top,
              right,
              bottom,
              left
            }}
          />
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default Boxes
```

*Some notes:*
I moved the functions outside of `useEffect` purely because it feels more clean that way but I'm not sure if there is any logical justification.
I'm using `.then()` to chain call the functions after making the API call but I wonder if this is an ok way to go about what I'm trying to achieve?

I'd really appreciate your feedback thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `async` and `await` for that purpose also instead of chained `.then`. See the example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const call = async () => {
        const result = await fetchApiData(imageSrc)
        const styles = await getBoxStyles(result)
        
        setBoxes(styles)
    }

    call()
}, [fetchApiData, imageSrc, getBoxStyles])
```

Comment: Cool! the second method however gives me this error: Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions. Put the async function inside

Comment: @Selo Just removed the second option, my bad! Thanks for the comment.